# How to get plain string data in Flash without XML parsing it?

Tags: xml, load, actionscript-2

I use the XML object a lot to load data into Flash. When XML object is in flash I then convert it to String (myData.toString()) and parse it using my delimiters.

However, when I'm loading a string data with `<>` tags such as:

```
Hi please state <name> <address>
```

this messes up the received data because XML treats the `<>` encapsulations as new nodes I think. So what i get is:

```
Hi please state
```

everything else after that is gone..

I could convert the <> tags to safe characters in PHP before output, but I'm wondering if there's a function in Flash AS2 to do this for me to read XML as pure string only?

I already tried:
    var headers:Array = new Array("Content-Type", "text/plain", "X-ClientAppVersion", "2.0");
    my_xml.addRequestHeader(headers);

but this didn't work.

I'd do `LoadVars` instead but I need to make this work with XML because `LoadVars` converts the incoming string into urlencoded while XML doesnt touch incoming data at all (my data can have special characters and it won't break. Only the `<>` breaks it.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to have plain text data, why are you using an XML loader to parse the XML file...?

anyways, if you insist on using that xml loader you could either:

- encapsulate the xml data into [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp), this will prevent any node parsing
- [format the XML properly](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp), because if you assign the root node to a string variable it **does** write everything out recursively, including all the nodes

**edit:**
if you want to use loadVars to load plain data only the trick is to use onData instead onLoad. an example of a plain text load (not variables load as var=value) from a text file (example from [as2 language reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001161.html):

```
var my_lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
my_lv.onData = function(src:String) {
    if (src == undefined) {
        trace("Error loading content.");
        return;
    }
    trace(src);
};
my_lv.load("content.txt", my_lv, "GET");
```

here you may also see a complete list of options of how to load some text data in actionscript 2: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000886.html

Comment: because i parse text data using CSV in my Flash.. and XML is the only thing i can think of to get almost every bit of character in plain text.. w/o having to encode/decode html entities and stuff like that.. loadVar would be great specially if i just do variable=value pairs on the whole block of text i want to parse.. but it has more problems w/ special characters, specially the "&" sign.. do you know of any other way to bring in plain, untouched text into flash? .. loading XML and converting to string is almost perfect except for those pesky "<>" chars in user inputs.

Comment: you don't have to use loadVars as variable=value. yes in that case you have to urlencode the assigned value (you probably forgot to urlencode it by the way). BUT you may also use loadVars class to load a plain text only- when you use onData handler instead of onLoad handler. let me update my answer for a complete example